# Что такое зависимости в Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Изучаю python-django. Но нигде не могу найти четкого определения термина "зависимости". Что это по сути, понимаю. Но может кто-то может дать четкое пояснение?

Comment: Если для работы вашему коду нужна какая-либо библиотека, то ваш код от неё зависим, а сама библиотека является для код зависимостью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код, как правило, делится на клиенты и службы.

Клиент - это программа, которая использует другую программу.

Служба - это программа, которую использует другая программа.

То есть клиентские программы, используют служебные программы. Если клиенту для работы необходим какой-то модуль(служебная программа), для работы, то эту программу можно назвать зависимостью. Так как от её наличия зависит работоспособность клиента.